# Why does android RemoteView class provide only setOnClickPendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, remoteview, android-remoteview

Android's `RemoteView` class provides the method `setOnClickPendingIntent` instead of `setOnClickListener`. What is the reason for this ? What's the advantage of using `PendingIntent` in this case ?

Comment: *iirc* A remote view is not running in your applications process, therefore it has to use IPC to tell your app something is clicked. This is asynchronous and so it is a "pending" click , not an instant click. The name reflects a subtle behaviour difference.

Comment: @Blundell make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

iirc

A remote view is not running in your applications process, therefore it has to use [IPC](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#IPC) to tell your app something is clicked. This is asynchronous and so it is a "pending" click, not an instant click. The name reflects a subtle behaviour difference.

[#setOnClickPendingIntent(int, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

vs

[#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Comment: There must be some behaviour differences between Intent and PendingIntent, otherwise `setOnClickIntent(int, Intent)` would be good enough to satisfy the subtle naming, non?

Comment: Yes but the question is not about `Intent` vs `PendingIntent` more about `onClick` from a `RemoteView` vs `onClick` from a `View`